# php-mysql-pdo: execute not working after prepare when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have following lines:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, content) VALUES :title, :content";
    $pre = $this->prepare($sql);
    $pre->bindValue(":title", "xxx");
    $pre->bindValue(":content", "yyy");
    $pre->execute();
```

I get no error, but the query is also not executed (i checked the query log).

I tried following changes desperately:

```
 $t="xxx" and $pre->bindValue(":title", $t); (the same also for y)
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `news` (`title`, `content`) VALUES :title, :content";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `news` (`title`, `content`) VALUES ':title', ':content'";
```

Nothing changes. Funny thing is i get no response, no warning, no error just nothing.
But the query is not executed.

I found similar posts but non of them solved my problem.

(about `$this` ... The code is in a class extended from PDO class.)

Comment: Don't forget about the method [`errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). Does that give you any errors?

Comment: it returns 00000. What does that mean?

Comment: If you were using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) or at least an ORM like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) you wouldn't need to fuss around with stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `"INSERT INTO news (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)";`

You must surround the insert values with parentheses.

Comment: It would make your answer a little better if you explained the subtle difference between this and the asker's code.

Answer (score 4):

try this, your values should be wrapped inside the `values()`

```
"INSERT INTO news (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)";
```

instead of

```
"INSERT INTO news (title, content) VALUES :title, :content";
```